# How to fix cloning error while cloning an object

Tags: java

I want to clone an object I created but it's giving me an error like this:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Teste

I'll leave the code below, I need to know how to solve this error and how many constructors do I need to make the code run.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Teste e1 = new Teste( "p2");
    Teste e2 = new Teste( "p2", 12.4f );
    Teste e3 = e1;
    Teste e4 = e2.clone();

}
```

Comment: First, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names are written in PascalCase, which means they start with uppercase.

Comment: clone returns an Object. You have to cast. `teste e4 = (teste)e2.clone();`

Comment: Second, share the code of the `teste` class (which you should rename to `Teste`).

Comment: you needs to explicitly cast back to the appropriate type

Comment: @MCEmperor I know I should, this is just a test code so I can learn the basics of cloning, thanks for the insight tho.

Comment: @matt  I tried, gives me another error "Unhandled exception type CloneNotSupportedException"

Comment: your teste class has to @override clone. The default clone just throws the exception you're getting now.

Comment: it's best if you first learn the basics, before starting with cloning

Comment: The first rule in the cloning club: don't use cloning in Java. Especially when you lack such basic knowledge about things like casting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow 2 rules to make custom objects clonable in java:

1. You must implement Cloneable interface.
2. You must override clone() method from Object class.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow 2 rules.
 1. implements Cloneable Interface
 2. clone returns an Object. You have to cast

Ex:

```
public class Teste implements Cloneable {
private String firstdata;
private float fdata;

public Teste(String data) {
    this.firstdata = data;
}

public Teste(String data, float fdata) {
    this.firstdata = data;
    this.fdata = fdata;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Teste e1 = new Teste("p2");
    Teste e2 = new Teste("p2", 12.4f);
    Teste e3 = e1;
    try {
        Teste e4 = (Teste) e2.clone();
        System.out.println(e4.firstdata);
        System.out.println(e4.fdata);

    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Occured");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}